# Looking for Appium download which can be supported to Android version 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using Nexus 5 Version 5.1.1
I have installed Appium but I am not able to find the Platform version 5.1.1

Searching on web for the latest appium but not sure whether it supports for 5.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Appium will support 5.1.1

You just mention your Android version in code i.e. pass your Android version in Desired Capabilities

```
    DesiredCapabilities cap1= new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap1.setCapability("deviceName", "deviceName");
    cap1.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1.1");
    cap1.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
```

1. In device Name you just mention your mobile device name.
2. In platform Version mention your Android Version.
3. In platform Name mention it as Android.

You cannot set the Andriod version in Appium UI, you have to pass it in program.